# Modify Playback Tempo of an AVAudioSequencer / AVMusicTrack?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-audio

How does one programmatically change the tempo (in BPM) of an `AVAudioSequencer` that's been loaded from an existing MIDI file (i.e. using the following)?

```
try sequencer.load(from: fileURL, options: AVMusicSequenceLoadOptions.smfChannelsToTracks)
```

I know that the sequencer's `tempoTrack` property returns the `AVMusicTrack` controlling the tempo, but how does one then edit it to add/change tempo events? The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosequencer/1390252-tempotrack) simply says...

> "The tempo track can be edited and iterated upon as any other track. Non-tempo events in a tempo track are ignored."

...but gives no further indication on how such editing would be done.

I know there's the `rate` property, but that just revolves around a default value of 1.0, which would need some complex adjustments to allow BPM values, and I don't think would even be possible unless the file's original BPM is known at runtime.

Alternatively, is there a way to create a new `AVMusicTrack` from scratch, with a custom tempo, and make *that* the sequencer's `tempoTrack`?

Comment: Just a tip, but maybe you could calculate the initial BPM dynamically using the `lengthInBeats` and `lengthInSeconds` properties of the track, and then adjust the `rate` property accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Great idea! Sucks that this is necessary, rather than being able to access the tempo directly (especially as it could change during parts of the track), but this is a viable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I managed this was to dip into the Audio Toolbox API momentarily.

This approach assumes that you instantiated your `AVAudioSequencer` with an `AVAudioEngine` via:

```
init(audioEngine engine: AVAudioEngine)
```

(1) After loading your midi file with `AVAudioSequencer`, get a pointer to the underlying `MusicSequence` from this property on `AVAudioEngine`

```
var musicSequence: MusicSequence? { get set }
```

(2) Get a pointer to the sequence's tempo track.

```
var tempoTrack: MusicTrack!
MusicSequenceGetTempoTrack(musicSequence, &tempoTrack)
```

(3) Remove all existing tempo information from the tempo track.

```
var iterator: MusicEventIterator!
NewMusicEventIterator(tempoTrack, &iterator)
var hasEvent = DarwinBoolean(false)
MusicEventIteratorHasCurrentEvent(iterator, &hasEvent)

while hasEvent.boolValue {
    var timeStamp = MusicTimeStamp()
    var eventType = MusicEventType()
    var data: UnsafeRawPointer? = nil
    var dataSize = UInt32()
        
    MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo(iterator, &timeStamp, &eventType, &data, &dataSize)
        
    guard eventType == kMusicEventType_ExtendedTempo else {
        MusicEventIteratorNextEvent(iterator)
        MusicEventIteratorHasCurrentEvent(iterator, &hasEvent)
        continue
    }
        
    // remove tempo event
    MusicEventIteratorDeleteEvent(iterator)
    MusicEventIteratorHasCurrentEvent(iterator, &hasEvent)
}

DisposeMusicEventIterator(iterator)
```

(4) Set the new tempo.

```
let bpm = 92
let timeStamp = MusicTimeStamp(0)
MusicTrackNewExtendedTempoEvent(tempoTrack, timeStamp, bpm)
```